# Form re-sizing kills form scrolling

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an base class which defines my common form functions, including scrolling.

I added form re-sizing capabilities to one of the descendants, and it has killed scrolling.

In the following extract the form is scrolling. If you un-comment the one line, it enables the form and fields to be re-sized as I want, but it scrolling is dead.

Can someone help please?

```
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk

class DisplayListWindow(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kw):
         Canvas.__init__(self,parent, borderwidth=0, *args, **kw)

        self.frame = Frame(self)
        vsb = Scrollbar(parent, orient="vertical", command=self.yview)
        self.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                              tags="self.frame")

        self.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)

        #remaining code in this function is from descendant classes
        for i in range(1, 20, 1):
            ttk.Entry(master=self.frame, style='C.TEntry').grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)
            ttk.Entry(master=self.frame, style='C.TEntry').grid(row = i, column = 1, sticky = NSEW)
            self.frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        #the following line enables the re-sizing behaviour, but kills scrolling
        #self.frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)   # <== problem     

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------        
    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox("all"))

DisplayListWindow().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a frame inside a canvas for the purposes of scrolling, you must add it to the canvas using `create_window` -- you *cannot* add it using `pack` or `grid`. These two methods (create_window, versus pack or grid) are incompatible with each other.

If you want the frame to resize when the window resizes, you'll have to add code to manually resize it.  You can do this by adjusting the width in your `<Configure>` callback.

For example:

```
def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    width = self.winfo_width() - 8 # allow room for some padding
    self.itemconfigure("self.frame", width=width)
    self.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox("all"))
```

Notice how I compute what the width should be by getting the width of the canvas, and then I use that value to set the width of the frame. The height is left to be the natural height of the frame, so the vertical scrollbar should always reflect the complete contents of the frame.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If adjust the Configure event as you suggest I see that it respects the column weightings, which was what I was wanting. This happens when the form is initially displayed, but if I manually re-size the form, the frame is not stretched as did happen when I was using pack. Is there some other event that I have to bind too?

Comment: OK, I see that the frame's configure event wasn't being called when the window was re-sized. I created another function, with your code, and bound it to self (the canvas) also. I added a code line to then trigger the frame's Configure event "self.OnFrameConfigure(self.frame)". It seems to all work OK now. <g> Thanks. Is there a more elegant or Pythonic way of rippling the event from the window down to the frame?

Comment: @BarryM: I don't quite understand your comment. When I took your original code and then added the code in my answer, the `<Configure>` event worked exactly as it should have. As for whether there's a more pythonic way, no, this is the proper way to do this.

Comment: re my comment: I am using Windows, I don't know if this is significant. When I dragged the window to a larger size, the OnFrameConfigure event bound to self.frame wasn't firing, so the window was re-sized but the frame wasn't. It all goes now that I have bound a similar function to the self's <Configure> event, and then manually call the OnFrameConfigure function as described above. Thanks for your help.